# Having trouble formatting the li and ul elements of a navigation in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I'm trying to format a navigation and its drop down in HTML and CSS.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/v29Laojv/)

I have two problems.

First, on the right of the navigation there is space. But it should go all to the right like on the left side.

Second, I can't get the drop down items to fit below each other.
Could u tell me where the problems of the right space and the drop down items are?

```css
/* Navi*/
 nav ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left:0;
}
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    width: 33%;
    text-align:center;
}
nav a {
    display: list-item;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
/* Dropdowns verstecken */
 nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
}
/* DropDowns */
 nav ul ul li {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    /*Üposition:relative;*/
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left:0;
}
/* DropDowns anzeigen */
 nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: inherit;
}
/* Highliting wenn angezeigt */
 nav a:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #8E96C0;
}
#kopfzeile {
    position: fixed;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #fa8072;
    font-family: Quicksand;
    opacity: 0.95;
    margin:auto;
}
a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
 <div id="kopfzeile">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#anker_id_html">| HTML+ |</a>

                    <!-- Erstes Drop Down -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Was ist HTML?</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Befehlsübersicht</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Beispiele</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#anker_id_css">| CSS+ |</a>

                    <!-- Zweites Drop Down -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Was ist CSS?</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Befehlsübersicht</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Beispiele</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#PHP">| PHP+ |</a>

                    <!-- Drittes Drop Down -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Was ist PHP</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Befehlsübersicht</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Beispiele</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Have a nice day,
Olker

Comment: No code in the question. Closing it as off-topic.

Comment: And make a simple fiddle to explain your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the Thread formatting request :)

Comment: @Olker Kumar has right, I also need to vote to close. I suggest to read and understand what the others say, it is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several changes you need to make this happen.

> **Note:** Before staring i guess you might have `body{margin:0px;}`. If not add it, but only if you want `nav` bar to leave no space.

**1)** Giving(adding) your **nav** `width:100%;` & `margin:0px;`. Along with the reason that your **nav** does not touches the right side is you need to give `width:100%;` to your `#kopfzeile`.

```
nav {
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
}
#kopfzeile {
    width: 100%; /* CHANGED */
}
```

**2)** Now remove `float:left;` by giving `float:none;` to your `nav ul ul li{...}`, to make them stack vertically. Along with that if you want text on left side also add `left-align:left;`

```
nav ul ul li
{
  float:none;
  text-align:left; /* Only if you want text left aligned*/
}
```

**Updated Below:**

**3)** For finishing to the `li` width's. You have `width:33%;` which is not actual dividing the `100%` So you need to make it `width:33.33%;`

```
nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  background-color: #1C1C1C;
  width: 33.33%; /* JUST CHANGED THIS ONE */
  text-align:center;
}
```

[JsFiddle : Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/v29Laojv/5/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for ur answer :)
The drop down looks bether now, thanks for that :)
But on ur fiddle u set the body margin to 0, but it also shows the red small space, or am i missing something?
Is there a way, the set the dropdown to the same width as the main menu items, without moving via px?

Comment: Or to make it more clear, the navigation should have a fixed length or width of 1000px, the 3 links in the main nav should excectly fit into that 1000px. The sub nav, or drop down, should have the width of the top element, in this case 1/3 of the 1000px.

Comment: @Olker Check out the update.

Comment: Thanks, i cant believe i´m to dumb to divide 100 by 3... Thanks..

Comment: No it happens, glad that it worked for you. You could upvote if you find it good.  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/upvote-thank-you.png

Comment: See i am asking you to do all this as i think you new in here, so just helping you out with Stack Overflow functionalities. If you know all these do not hate me ;)

Comment: Nono, i´m happy about it :) Yes i´m new.. i upvoted ur answer but it says i have to get some points untill it will be shown the public :D